# Css template not the same in all browsers (overlaying div)

Tags: html, css

Basically i have 2 columns and the left side has an overlaying grey image to create a kind of blur effect. When you mouseover it, it will turn see-through. It works well in Chrome/Safari but not in Firefox and i can't really figure out why.

I uploaded a link to my site to show what i mean:

http://generowicz.nl/showing_template.html

When viewed in Firefox the overlaying image doesnt fit and overlay the whole left side.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
 font-family: Helvetica;
 font-weight: lighter;
}
#left{
 text-indent:1cm;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
 background: rgba(51,51,51,1);
}

#right {
 padding-top:2cm;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background: white;
}

#img {
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0.4;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 pointer-events:none;
 -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
 -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
 transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
 color:#000;
}

#left:hover>#img {
  opacity: 0;
}

h1{
 font-size: 80px;
 color:#CCC;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #CCC;
 font-weight: lighter;
}

h3 {
 font-size: 15px;
 color:#CCC;
}

/* These are for main body */
h4 {
 font-size: 15px;
 color:#000;
}

h5 {
 font-size: 15px;
 color:#000;
 font-weight: lighter;
}
 


a.one:link {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #CCC;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;   Saf3.2+, Chrome 
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;   FF4+ 
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;   IE10 
       -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;   Opera 10.5+ 
          transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}  

a.one:link:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #09F;
}

a.one:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
 color: #CCC;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;   Saf3.2+, Chrome 
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;   FF4+ 
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;   IE10 
       -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;   Opera 10.5+ 
          transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    }
    
a.one:visited:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #09F;
}
a.one:active { text-decoration: none;
 color: #CCC;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;   Saf3.2+, Chrome 
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;   FF4+ 
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;   IE10 
       -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;   Opera 10.5+ 
          transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="left"><img src="images/graysmall.png" name="img" width="93" height="55" id="img" />
  <h1> B </h1>
  <h2><a class="one" href="../index.html">Home</a></h2>
  <h2><a class="one" href="../about.html">About Me</a></h2>
  <h2><a class="one" href="../contact.html">Contact</a></h2>
</div>

<div id="right">


<table width="100%" border="0" align="left">
  <tr>
    <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="95%" align="left" valign="top">
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="Content" -->
   
    
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Why do you not use hover opacity effect?
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Comment: I am not sure why you are changing the opacity of an image to achieve this effect. You can remove the image and do it on the `<div id="left">` `background-color` and get the same effect also the user wont have to download an unneeded image speeding up the download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding ***left:0*** in your ***#img*** class will give the result you need. See the updated class below,

```
#img {
position: absolute;
opacity: 0.4;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
pointer-events: none;
-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
-o-transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
color: #000;
left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not commented these lines Saf3.2+, Chrome , FF4+  etc

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome all these text should be comment*/
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out; /*  FF4+ */
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out; /*  IE10 */
       -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out; /*  Opera 10.5+ */
          transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything but thanks for the suggestion